# Choice of model for prognostic value of asymptomatic recurrence detection

Tags: stata, clinical-trials, medicine

I am involved in the final step of a project that evaluates the prognostic value of asymptomatic vs. symptomatic recurrence detection; all subjects experienced recurrence.

The project proposed a model that includes the binary variable *symptoms* (asy | sy) controlled for 2 sets of variables: **baseline variables** (@BL) and **variables collected at the time of recurrence** (eg lab tests) (@Rec).

M1: symptoms + @BL + @Rec

Since asymptomatic recurrence is expected to be detected early before symptoms occur, the model should account for time to recurrence and may include *symptoms*, *months-to recurrence*, and the *interaction term*.

M2: symptoms & mths-to-recurrence & Interaction + @BL + @Rec

Another approach would be to use a time-varying approach and create 2 entries per subject; 1-st where the subject is at risk of recurrence and 2-nd post recurrence and generate an indicator variable for asymptomatic recurrence (Y/N). This model will include *symptoms*, *months-to recurrence*, and *indicator for asymptomatic recurrence*.

M3: symptoms & mths-to-recurrence & asymptomatic_recurrence + @BL + @Rec

I would appreciate your opinion, recommendations and references regarding the best model.